# How to convert HttpPostedFileBase file to Java.Io.InputStream?

Tags: java, c#, ikvm, mpxj

I'm working on ASP.net with the MPXJ library. The .net version of MPXJ has been created using IKVM.

Currently, I have a big problem: After upload a file (Microsoft Project file - .mpp file) to server (I don't need to save it), I want to convert from HttpPostedFileBase to the IKVM version of java.io.InputStream and MPXJ will manipulate them, but I don't know a way to implement this.
My code:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
   // Todo: Convert from HttpPostedFileBase to Java.Io.InputStream
   ProjectReader reader = new MPPReader();
   ProjectFile projectObj = reader.read(Java.Io.InputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a wrapper to provide a conversion between the IKVM Java type java.io.InputStream and a .net Stream instance. As luck would have it, IKVM ships with one...

Using the wrapper, your example will now look like this:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
   ProjectReader reader = new MPPReader();
   ProjectFile projectObj = reader.read(new ikvm.io.InputStreamWrapper(files.InputStream));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use IKVM, you can implement as below:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
     byte[] fileData = null;
     using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(files.InputStream))
     {
        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(files.ContentLength);
     }  
     ProjectFile projectObj = reader.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData));
}
```